# XERO API: Is there documentation that lists which tables are available to developers?

Tags: xero-api

Looking for a list of tables that are accessible to developers to make sure we can accomplish what we're hoping to before going through all of the effort to get the data into Azure. Anything someone can share?

Adam

Xero's documentation is frustrating, as some of it is out of date and references long-dead information.

Comment: The only documentation I'm aware of is the API reference on developer.xero.com, and the source code to the various APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Xero API Explorer to verify at

https://developer.xero.com/announcements/all-new-api-explorer

You're wise to verify this before starting coding as there are *a lot* of oddities (and omissions) in the API.